# fill between two radius of circle by geometry shader with radius

Tags: colors, gradient, geometry, segment, geometry-shader

I'm confused in using geometry shader for solve this problem:
I have two radius of a circle that every radius is a line and I called that's a line. every line is made of list of points that every points have a color.
so how fill between two lines with lines that's color of every point on a line has between colors of points of two lines on a equal radius.
it is so may be complex so I show it with a picture:

[gradient Radiuses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKkGA.png) 
.

I think best way of solving this problem is geometry shader but if you know better way that have good performance, I listen.
thanks.